# Creating child class based on class content

Tags: java, inheritance, parent-child, multiple-inheritance

I have a class structure like this:

```
                        LineTemplate (abstract)
                        /                    \
                LineOut (abstract)        LineIn (final)
                /                \
LineOutTransfers (final)     LineOutSells (final)
```

Both *LineOut* and *LineIn* should read a line from a file, check its content against a database and run multiple queries.

*LineOut*, however, contains two slightly different variations, which depend on the contents of the line. Due to the fact that *LineOutTransfers* and *LineOutSells* perform different actions when their methods are called, I decided to inherit and treat them as subclasses.

I created a **public static LineTemplate __init()** method within *LineTemplate* to determine whether it is a *LineOut* or *LineIn* class and return the correct type based on external conditions, and I wanted to implement a similar method to determine the correct type of *LineOut* subclass.

Since the *LineOut* child depends on the line content, however, I'm stuck at this point. The class should read the line, then convert itself to the correct child and then perform the checks. But this is impossible as I cannot cast a parent class into a child, if it is not already of that type (*polymorphism*).

I also thought about reading all the line inside *LineOut*'s **__init()** method, and then passing the variables as arguments to its child constructor, but since there are a bunch of variables to be read and since it is done differently inside *LineIn*, it seemed to me like a bad practice.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds to me like inheritance isn't the right design here, but it's too vague a description for an informed judgement.

Comment: @daniu I did think about a simple boolean flag, but there are too many differences among the methods of the two children... What do you suggest instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Favor composition over inheritance, so instead of

```
abstract class LineOut {
  public void consume(Line l) {
    // ...
    subclassConsume(l);
    // ...
  }
  protected abstract void subclassConsume(Line l);
}
// and
class LineOutTransfers extends LineOut {
  protected abstract void subclassConsume(Line l) { ... }
}
class LineOutSells extends LineOut {
  protected abstract void subclassConsume(Line l) { ... }
}
```

you should do this

```
abstract class LineOut {
  private TransferLineHandler transferHandler;
  private SellsLineHandler sellsHandler;
  public void consume(Line l) {
    // ...
    if (isTransfer(l)) {
      transferHandler.consume(l);
    } else {
      sellsHandler.consume(l);
    }
    // ...
  }
  protected abstract void subclassConsume(Line l);
}
// with
class TransferLineHandler {
  public consume(l) { // stuff from LineOutTransfers }
}
class SellsLineHandler {
  public consume(l) { // stuff from LineOutSells }
}
```

This removes the "dynamic subclassing" issue altogether and makes the code more testable.

Comment: Damn that's smart! Thank you. I guess that **consume()** inside _TransferLineHandler_ and _TransferLineHandler_ should be **static**, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Shish preferably not. I did add each of the handlers as a member, you'd need to instantiate those somewhere. You might only be able to have all required data to do that when you call the consume method, in which case you don't need the members.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add a `convertWithContext(SomeClassRepresentingContext ctx)` method to `LineOut` that will return a new `LineOut` that will be the correct subclass of LineOut?

Another approach would be to use a Factory method and supply it the line content and the context. Something like

```java
LineOutFactory.instance().constructLineOut(String line, SomeClassRepresentingContext ctx);
```

In Java you cannot change the type of a class once it is created you can only build a new class based on the content of the existing class and possibly external context.

Comment: Sound good! But what should I write within that method? Do I have to pass each variable one by one?

Comment: You’d need enough code to construct the object. Not sure what you mean by pass each variable one by one. All the variables used by the constructor must be available when the constructor is called. If using subclasses is awkward another  option to using inheritance is to use Interfaces. Hard to know the best solution without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a factory method would be useful for this scenario: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method

Comment: Read it... But it doesn't help! I need to be able to choose the class type after it has been created.